# React.JS - using data to create for loop limits in image array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, for-loop, graphql

I have a hero component which has a forward and backward button that I want to use for scrolling through images coming from a database collection based on that listing so the images in the array would vary sometimes based on how many images there are in the image array of that listing.

I'm trying to figure out how I can create functions to use the left and right arrows to move forward or backwards in the image array. I was thinking of just creating a for loop to  move through the array, but I want to be able to set a limit on the index based on the image array limit per listing since a listing with 5 images will stop showing anything after image[4] while a listing with 20 images will keep going past that.

App.js

```js
export default class App extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        language: "english"
    };
}

render() {
    return <Fragment>
        <Header language={this.state.language} />
        <Hero />
        <Navigation />
        <Overview />
        <Reviews />
    </Fragment>;
   }
}
```

Hero.js

```js
class Hero extends Component {
render() {
    const { listing: { images = [], name } = {} } = this.props;
    return <div className="hero">
        <img src={images[0]} alt="listing" />
        <a className="hero__arrow hero__arrow--left">◀</a>
        <a className="hero__arrow hero__arrow--right">▶</a>
        <div className="hero__info">
            <h1>{name}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>;
}
}

const getHero = gql`
query getHero {
    listing {
        name
        images
    }
}
`;

export default function HeroHOC(props) {
return <Query
    query={getHero}
>
    {({ data }) => (
        <Hero
            {...props}
            listing={data && data.listing || {}} // eslint-disable-line no-mixed-operators
        />
    )}
</Query>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the name is same for each listing, you use `.map` property of array.

```js
return <div className="hero">
  {images.map((image, index) => 
    <img src={image} key={`image-${index}`} alt="listing" />
  )}
  <div className="hero__info">
    <h1>{name}</h1>
  </div>
</div>;
```

if you want to use arrow clicks for image change, you have to write click handler for them

```js
return <div className="hero">
  <img src={this.state.images[this.state.currIndex]} alt="listing" />
  <a className="hero__arrow hero__arrow--left" onClick={this.handleClick('left')} >◀</a>
  <a className="hero__arrow hero__arrow--right" onClick={this.handleClick('right')}>▶</a>
  <div className="hero__info">
    <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
  </div>
</div>;

 handleClick = (leftOrRight) => {
   if (leftOrRight === 'left' && this.state.currIndex > 0) {
     this.setState({
       currIndex: this.state.currIndex - 1;
     })
   } else if (leftOrRight === 'left' && this.state.currIndex < this.state.images.length - 1){
     this.setState({
       currIndex: this.state.currIndex + 1;
     })
   }
 }

 // and finally do not forget to load the images in state in constructor

 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   // set image state here
 }
```